# Using (v)lookup for 2 documents without importing it

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup, importrange

Would it be possible to compare 2 tables from different documents with lookup without importing the document in the one I want to write the formula? If so, could I get a general example of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can import it into the formula directly:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Sheet1!A:B"), 2, 0)))
```

but note that spreadsheets need to be connected first